# React.js: Set image as div background inside map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Trying to set image as div background inside map function in React.js project, but I can't access **post.featured_image_src** outside map function and set as background in the *divStyle* variable:

```
class Archive extends Component {
    render() {
        let allPosts = DataStore.getAllPosts();
        let pageData = DataStore.getPageBySlug('archive');
        let acf = pageData.acf;

        const divStyle = {
          backgroundImage: 'url(' + post.featured_image_src + ')'
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{pageData.title.rendered}</h1>
                <div className="post-container">
                  <div className="post-wrapper">
                    {allPosts.map((post, i) => {
                      return (
                        <div className="post" key={i}>
                          {post.featured_image_src
                            ? <a href={post.link}><div style={divStyle}/></a>
                            : null}
                          <h3 className="post-title"><a href={post.link} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:post.title.rendered}} /></h3>
                        </div>
                      )
                    }
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Any tips would be oh so lovely .. <3

Comment: move const divStyle = { backgroundImage: 'url(' + post.featured_image_src + ')'  } inside .map loop

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `post` is not defined when you try to access it to define styles

```
  const divStyle = {
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + post.featured_image_src + ')'
    }
```

You could move have this logic as a function

```
     const divStyle = (src) => ({
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + src + ')'
    })

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{pageData.title.rendered}</h1>
            <div className="post-container">
              <div className="post-wrapper">
                {allPosts.map((post, i) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="post" key={i}>
                      {post.featured_image_src
                        ? <a href={post.link}><div style={divStyle(post.featured_image_src)}/></a>
                        : null}
                      <h3 className="post-title"><a href={post.link} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:post.title.rendered}} /></h3>
                    </div>
                  )
                }
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

For obvious reasons you cannot use the variable before its defined.

You can rather replace `<div style={divStyle}/>` with:

```
<div style={ backgroundImage: "url(" + post.featured_image_src + ")" } />
```

**OR**, as suggested by @Shubham, use a method that will return the desired style object:

```
const divStyle = (imgSrc) => ({
  backgroundImage: `url(${imgSrc})`
})
```

In render:

```
<div style={this.divStyle(post.featured_image_src)}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ post.featured_image_src 
  ? <a href={post.link}>
       <div className="post-img" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${post.featured_image_src})`}}/>
    </a>
  : null
}
```